# IllegalArgumentException on JobIntentService mainly on Samsung devices

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception, samsung-galaxy, jobintentservice

I get a lot of IllegalArgumentException crashes which I cannot reproduce. 99% of them are from Samsung Galaxy devices.
This is the log from Play Store Console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done (AsyncTask.java:354)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion (FutureTask.java:383)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException (FutureTask.java:252)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:271)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  at android.app.job.JobParameters.completeWork (JobParameters.java:268)
  at android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService$JobServiceEngineImpl$WrapperWorkItem.complete (JobIntentService.java:268)
  at android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground (JobIntentService.java:394)
  at android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground (JobIntentService.java:383)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:333)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
```

I have 6 JobInentServices which each one updates a widget. Every JobIntentService has a unique 5-digit JOB_ID to avoid any possible conflict with JOB_ID from libraries.

Before my last update I used other JOB_IDs because I suspected that some ID was causing this exception. Now with the new IDs there Is a big increment of these crashes.

Is the change the cause of this? Does the app "remember" the old IDs and now there 2 different IDs for the same JobIntentService?
Why this is happening only on Samsung devices?
Could be intent the root of this exception?
Is there any way to solve this problem?

My code from widget provider:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        WidgetEcoService.class);
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);
                WidgetEcoService.enqueueWork(context.getApplicationContext(), intent);
```

My code from JobIntentService:

```
public static final int JOB_ID = 45454;
public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent work) {
        enqueueWork(context, WidgetEcoService.class, JOB_ID, work);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to "[The CommonsBlog](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/06/07/jobscheduler-job-ids-libraries.html)":

```
    The docs point out that the id needs to be stable across app updates,
and therefore an id resource is unsuitable
```

So the answer is that changing the JOB_ID in my last update was a mistake by myself and I can't do anything now.

Comment: Have you solved the problem eventually? I am having the same problem....

Comment: Unfortunattely there is nothing to do if you change JOB_ID.